# How to instantiate a new tile randomly and destroy them

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on this infinite runner game.
I have 5 tiles with different colors and I want them to spawn in the same y axis but not spawn the same tile consecutively.

Like **[Bluetile][Greentile][Purpletile][Bluetile]Magentatile][Bluetile]**

I want them to destroy when out of the camera as well.

I only know C# and I'm looking forward for your anticipated assistance! :)

Comment: Show us your code and and specify where you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the tiles, you should insert all the tiles to a list and when you need to get a new tile you simply randomly select a tile from the list minus the last object on the list (guaranting that he won't be picked again for a second time) and then push that tile to the end of the list.

```
// populating the tiles
List<Tile> tiles = new List<Tile>();
 // todo: populate the tiles list


// getting a tile and pushing it to the end
int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, tiles.Count - 1);
Tile tile = tiles[randomIndex];
tiles.RemoveAt(randomIndex);
tiles.Add(tile);
```

and as for destroying the tiles once the leave the screen, there's a method the monobehaviour class that detects when an object leaves the camera

```
void OnBecameInvisible() {
     Destroy(gameobject);
}
```

Comment: Late reply here, but Thank you so much!!!! :) kind of got the gist and edited some of the code!